# Laravel Excel import not working if passing the form file

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am facing a strange problem while importing the `xlsx` files. According to the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html)

```
If you let your user upload the document, you can also just pass the uploaded file directly.
Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('your_file'));
```

I am using the same instructions in my below code.
**My Controller Code**

```
 public function import(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Excel::import(new customer,  request()->file('file'));
            return redirect('import-customers')->with('success', 'File Imported Successfully!');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            return back()->with('error', __('Invalid File Structure!'));
        }
    }
```

**Customer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\customerModel;
use App\CustomFieldable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class customer implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
   
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        \Log::debug('working...'); //it is not triggering this function
    }
}
```

I don't know the exact reason behind this. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Any error message

Comment: @Shibon no. Not anything in the logs

Comment: ```request()->file('file')``` dump and check if there is any data

Comment: try accessing data like this ```$request->file('file')```

Comment: it is giving this response

Comment: Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#11253 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "customer-template (6).xlsx"
  -mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "D:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "php5D7C.tmp"
  basename: "php5D7C.tmp"
  pathname: "D:\xampp\tmp\php5D7C.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "D:\xampp\tmp\php5D7C.tmp"
  aTime: 2022-09-05 12:45:46
  mTime: 2022-09-05 12:45:46
  cTime: 2022-09-05 12:45:46
  inode: 1125899907093833
  size: 7478
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: tru

Answer (score 0):

Make a new import file with the first letter in capital and add Import to the end of it

something like this:

```
try {
    Excel::import(new CustomerImport,  request()->file('file'));
    return redirect('import-customers')->with('success', 'File Imported Successfully!');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
    return back()->with('error', __('Invalid File Structure!'));
}
```

Comment: I have renamed the class and filename as well but it is still not working

Comment: check the top and change the class for excel to use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

Comment: It is already there. It would have given a straight fatal error if not added.

Comment: Check the filename in the blade directive if its the same as the one being requested in the controller